# Is there a term for $P(A\cap B)/[P(A)P(B)]$?

Tags: probability, correlation, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does this quantity related to independence have a name?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6047/does-this-quantity-related-to-independence-have-a-name)

Is there a term for the joint probability of two events $A$ and $B$ over a product of the probability of the event $A$ and the probability of the event $B$, i.e.:

$$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)P(B)}?$$

Perhaps something like "relative joint probability"?

Needless to say, by definition, it is 1 when $A$ and $B$ are [independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)).